# Export settings for KeePass?

Tags: keepass

I'm using KeePass 2.39.1 as a shared password utility.  I would like to make sure everyone else is using the same settings I'm using (autolock, etc).  I don't see any way to export the settings.  Am I missing it? Is there a utility?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Settings are stored in a file named `KeePass.config.xml`. For portable installations, the file is typically located in the same directory as `KeePass.exe`.

> KeePass supports multiple locations for storing configuration information: the global configuration file in the KeePass application directory, a local user-dependent one in the user's private configuration folder, and an enforced configuration file in the KeePass application directory. The first one is called global, because everyone using this KeePass installation will write to the same configuration file (and possibly overwriting settings of other users). The second one is called local, because changes made to this configuration file only affect the current user.

[KeePass Configuration Details](https://keepass.info/help/base/configuration.html).

Comment: The docs you linked talk about `KeePass.config.enforced.xml` which is perfect. Thanks!